# ContentPresenter loads resource only first occurence [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter

I have WPF view, where I use buttons with style that I created by myself. In this style I use some icon from resources, that I pass by TemplateBinding. 
Unfortunately I faced strange problem: the resource is shown only at first occurrence of button with this style. In next buttons I have empty box.

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="13" Height="15"  x:Name="IconBrush">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="DarkGray"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="IconBrush"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="Black" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="IconBrush" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="DarkGray" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Usege:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="20 0">
    <Button Height="35" Width="35" Margin="3 3" Content="{StaticResource trash}" Style ="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"/>
    <Button Height="35" Width="35" Margin="3 3" Content="{StaticResource trash}"  Style ="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

What is interesting, when I use another resources, they work at their first occurrences. So if I use `another_res` instead of `trash`, it works at first time.

How do I fix it?

***EDIT:***

Next tests show, that when I use any resource in style and problem repeats:

```
<VisualBrush.Visual>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource some_resource}" />
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```

***EDIT2:***
The resource is defined in external source:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

As canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Key="trash" Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Data="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" Fill="Black" />
</Canvas>
```

---

Comment: Which version of .Net framework are you targeting in your project? That can be helpful in finding the issue as some key things have changed in how color instances are handled in templated styles and animations across different version of .Net

Comment: It's .NET 4.5. Application build for 64bit.

Comment: @KubaMatjanowski how are you changing trash resource? how is it defined in xaml?

Comment: @KyloRen I edited the question giving this information.

Comment: @KubaMatjanowski try using VisualBrush I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Don't*** define your `Icons` like(I hope this is your problem as this is what people usually do, and Image is a `FrameworkElement`):

```
 <Image Source="Resources/SOF.gif" x:Key="trash"/>
```

Define them like:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/SOF.gif" x:Key="trash"/>
```

and use `ImageBrush` like(in your style):

```
 <Rectangle Width="113" Height="95"  x:Name="IconBrush" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=Content}"/>
```

your Icons will be repeated on buttons like below:

[image]

**Update:**

try it like:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="trash" >
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas  Width="24" Height="24" >
                <Path Data="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" Fill="Black" />
            </Canvas>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

**OutPut:(make sure to use `Rectangle` fill correctly as I have mentioned above)**

[image: buttons]

Comment: Okey, It does work! Even if I fut canvas directly to button content and I use it as 'parameter'.
But the question now is - why I can't use resources in the `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: @KubaMatjanowski you can put a resource in ContentPresenter. But that will of a control derived from FrameworkElement like an Image or Canvas, In your example if you put Canvas directly inside ContentPresenter content that will be visible. but only once cause a control can't have two different parents in a visual tree.

Comment: So FrameworkElement type in ContentPresenter and Brushes in fill property are accepted in WPF.simply. and FrameworkElement are not shared/reusable. but a same brush can be used in many conntrols.